# UCanAccess reads the last column of a table as the first column

Tags: java, jdbc, ucanaccess

My program always reads the first column in the Access database as the 2nd column, the 2nd one as the 3rd column and so on, but the last column it reads as the first column.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  try{
    String query = "insert into Staff values ('2', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'e', 'w', 'd','d','end')";
    stmt.executeUpdate(query);
    status.setText("1 row of record have been inserted");
  }catch(Exception ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

But when i specify the column names, it reads normally

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  try{
    String query = "insert into Staff (id, lastName, firstName, mi, address, city, state, telephone, email) "
    + "values ('2', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'e', 'w', 'd','d','end')";
    stmt.executeUpdate(query);
    status.setText("1 row of record have been inserted");
  }catch(Exception ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, UCanAccess treats the columns of a table in "DATA" order. That is the order in which the columns have been defined internally in the Access metadata, which can be different from the "DISPLAY" order.

If you want UCanAccess to treat the columns in "DISPLAY" order, then add the argument

```
;columnOrder=DISPLAY
```

to the end of your connection URL, e.g.,

```
jdbc:ucanaccess://c:/db/cico.mdb;columnOrder=DISPLAY
```

However, you should also realize by now that by *not* specifying the actual column names in your INSERT statement you are leaving your code vulnerable to breakage by *assuming* the names (and order) of the columns.

Just as `SELECT * FROM` is frowned upon, so is `INSERT INTO tablename VALUES ( ...`. You are already specifying the *values* for each column so you really should be specifying the *names* of the columns as well.

Comment: Is there a standard programming technique to deal with databases in Java ? I'm using the book “introduction to java programming” by Y.Daniel. The book only use a sql query to deal with databases, but i 've seen many ways online, like using a data class, mvc, dao etc.

Comment: OMG, u really solve my problem! thanks alot!!!